# Parsing Model data into JQuery array

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I have a model that is returning absence data and it has the View Model of:

```
public class Absence
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public int startDate { get; set; }

    public int startMonth { get; set; }

    public int startYear { get; set; }

    public int endDate { get; set; }

    public int endMonth { get; set; }

    public int endYear { get; set; }
}
```

I am aiming to put these onto a calendar control on the front end in a visual manner. This is a third party tool available at http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/, and in order to get this data into the calendar I need to set the dataSource property when I initialise the control. In their example they show a the data source being set like:

```
dataSource: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: 'Google I/O',
                location: 'San Francisco',
                startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
                endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 29)
            }
        ]
```

So I am trying to get my list of holidays that I have retrieved from a database, and stored in a list of my View Model type, into the same format as what the data source expects.

I've tried to convert the model data into an array by first encoding it via JSON and then parsing it back into an object, like below:

```
var test = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var object = $.parseJSON(test);
```

Encoding it seems to work alright but when it comes to parsing it I get an error saying there is an invalid character. I'm not great with using JSON so i'm not sure which particular character it isn't happy with. But I have posted an example record from the JSON string below:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Unpaid Sickness","type":"Bob Smith","startDate":11,"startMonth":4,"startYear":2016,"endDate":11,"endMonth":4,"endYear":2016}]
```

Can someone help me find what the issue is, or if you know of a better way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

This is the full error message i'm getting:

> Unhandled exception at line 564, column 4 in http://localhost:59082/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js
>
> 0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

**EDIT 2**

I've done a bit of messing round with it and i've come up with a version that works, but this is hardcoded. So when I have it parse the following:

```
'{"id": "0", "name": "Unpaid Sickness","location": "James Peel","startDate": "11","startMonth": "4","startYear": "2016","endDate": "11","endMonth": "4","endYear": "2016"}';
```

It works fine. So I don't know if it's complaining because what is passed in from the model is an object rather than a simple bit of text.

Thanks

Comment: the string looks fine to me... doesn't the error say which one is the erroneous character? you could try putting the members of the array into different lines, maybe it will help you pointing out which line is incorrect...

Comment: @webeno No it's not saying anything about which character it doesn't like, I've updated the main post with the full error message it shows, and this doesn't change when I move it onto separate lines

Comment: where did you get your copy of jQuery from? it looks like pointing to that, so either you link to an online version of it (or download a recent one), though from experience, if an error is pointing to jQuery, it usually means that the error is somewhere completely different... best practice is to go back to a previously working code and try to apply new code in smaller bits...